# iOSのステータスバーを動的変更(Unityプラグイン使用)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity3d

UnityのPluginを用いて、
iOSのステータスバーを動的に表示・非表示にさせたいのですが
Unityからコールされた*.mや*.mmファイルからどのようにして
UntyのViewControllerのステータスバーにアクセスしたら良いかがわかりません。

ヒントでも構いませんので知見をお持ちでしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- iOS8.1.3
- Unity4.6.1p4

の環境で以下の手法で変更できることを確認しました。
しかしながら対象部分のソースコードには `we do not support changing styles from script, so we need read info.plist only once` と書かれているので変更した結果何が起きるかはわかりません。

- `Assets/Plugins/iOS/bridge.h`

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// ViewController を取得する関数
typedef UIViewController*(^sample_get_view_controller_func)(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */
    // Unity の ViewController を取得する関数を登録
    void sample_set_get_root_view_controller_func(sample_get_view_controller_func f);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

- `Assets/Plugins/iOS/bridge.m`

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "bridge.h"

static sample_get_view_controller_func s_get_view_controller_func;

void sample_set_get_root_view_controller(sample_get_view_controller_func f)
{
    s_get_view_controller_func = [f copy];
}

// Unity から呼び出す関数
void sample_update_status_bar_(int is_show)
{
    if(s_get_view_controller_func != NULL) {
        UIViewController* vc = s_get_view_controller_func();
        if(vc != nil){
            // is_show を使用して表示フラグを変更
            ...
            [vc setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];    // ステータスバーの更新。
                                                       // 結果後で修正する PrefersStatusBarHidden_DefaultImpl が呼び出される。
        }
    }
}
```

上記で定義した `sample_update_status_bar_` を Unity から呼び出せる状態にして Xcode プロジェクトを出力します。

- 出力した xcode プロジェクトの `UnityAppController.mm`

---

```
#include "../Libraries/bridge.h"
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    // Unity の ViewController にアクセスできる関数を登録
    __unsafe_unretained typeof(self) wself = self;
    sample_set_get_root_view_controller_func(^UIViewController*(){
        return wself.rootViewController;
    });
    ...
```

- 出力した xcode プロジェクトの `UnityViewControllerBase.mm`

---

```
BOOL
PrefersStatusBarHidden_DefaultImpl(id self_, SEL _cmd)
{
    // 既存の処理は info.plist からステータスバーの表示/非表示を制限するようになっているので
    // 全部コメントアウトする。
    //  // we do not support changing styles from script, so we need read info.plist only once
    //  static BOOL _PrefersStatusBarHidden = YES;
    //
    //  static bool _PrefersStatusBarHiddenInited = false;
    //  if(!_PrefersStatusBarHiddenInited)
    //  {
    //      NSNumber* hidden = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"UIStatusBarHidden"];
    //      _PrefersStatusBarHidden = hidden ? [hidden boolValue] : YES;
    //
    //      _PrefersStatusBarHiddenInited = true;
    //  }
    //
    //  return _PrefersStatusBarHidden;

    // とりあえず例として、呼び出すたびに表示/非表示が切り替わるよう
    // 例えば `sample_update_status_bar_` で取得する値を使用するように
    // 処理に変更すれば、Unity 上から好きなタイミングで制御できる
    static BOOL hidden = YES;
    hidden = !hidden;
    return hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

文字数足りなかったので回答に書きます、
下記サイトを参考に実装したところUnityのプラグイン経由で
ステータスバーOn・Offできましたので共有いたします。
http://blog.doinet.co.jp/?eid=1031808

UnityViewControllerBase.mm

```
// ステータスバーの非表示
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return self.view.tag == 999 ? NO:YES;//NOのとき非表示となる
}


//- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
//{
//  static bool _PrefersStatusBarHidden = true;
//
//  static bool _PrefersStatusBarHiddenInited = false;
//  if(!_PrefersStatusBarHiddenInited)
//  {
//      NSNumber* hidden = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]     objectForKey:@"UIStatusBarHidden"];
//      _PrefersStatusBarHidden = hidden ? [hidden boolValue] : YES;
//
//      _PrefersStatusBarHiddenInited = true;
//  }
//  return _PrefersStatusBarHidden;
//}
```

Plugin/iOS 直下に置く自作のソース

statusbar.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
//#include "iPhone_View.h"

extern UIViewController* UnityGetGLViewController();

//extern "C" void StatusBarOn()
void StatusBarOn()
{
    UIViewController* parent = UnityGetGLViewController();
    parent.view.tag = 999;
    [parent setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

//extern "C" void StatusBarOff()
void StatusBarOff()
{
    UIViewController* parent = UnityGetGLViewController();
    parent.view.tag = 0;
    [parent setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];    
}
```

Comment: `UnityGetGLViewController` を使えば簡単にかけるのですね。